# Android : Help in compiling SoundTouch lib in android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to compile the [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/)  lib with Android NDK. I got some instruction from [Here](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/faq.html#compiling) to compile this lib in android.

But when I try to compile it with `ndk-build` command it show errors in various source files of SoundTouch lib something like this: [image]

I tried to Switch off exception handling as mentioned in the instructions but it doesn't seems to work.

I copied all the files from SoundTouch source to JNI folder of my project. Here is my `android.mk` file :

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS :- -frtti -fexceptions

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AAFilter.cpp BPMDetect.cpp cpu_detect_x86.cpp FIFOSampleBuffer.cpp FIRFilter.cpp main.cpp mmx_optimized.cpp PeakFinder.cpp RateTransposer.cpp RunParameters.cpp SoundTouch.cpp sse_optimized.cpp TDStretch.cpp WavFile.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lpcap

LOCAL_MODULE := libSoundTouch

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := BPMDetect.h FIFOSampleBuffer.h FIFOSamplePipe.h SoundTouch.h STTypes.h

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Can anyone please help me to compile and use SoundTouch lib on android?

**UPDATE :**

I changed my `android.mk` file as below

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += -fno-exceptions

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
     SoundTouch/AAFilter.cpp \
     SoundTouch/BPMDetect.cpp \
     SoundTouch/cpu_detect_x86.cpp\
      SoundTouch/FIFOSampleBuffer.cpp \
      SoundTouch/FIRFilter.cpp \
      SoundTouch/mmx_optimized.cpp \
      SoundTouch/PeakFinder.cpp \
      SoundTouch/RateTransposer.cpp \
      SoundTouch/SoundTouch.cpp \
      SoundTouch/sse_optimized.cpp \
      SoundTouch/TDStretch.cpp 

LOCAL_MODULE := libSoundTouch

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := include/BPMDetect.h include/FIFOSampleBuffer.h include/FIFOSamplePipe.h include/SoundTouch.h include/STTypes.h

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And now its working all fine. Thank you

Comment: To enable exceptions you need to use "LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := exceptions rtti" in Android.mk file. What is the first error you are getting and on which line exactly?

Comment: Hey, What you had done to build this library?? Just copy the Android.mk, Aplication.mk and soundtouch-jni.cpp ina new android project. and build it by NDK-build command ...I am following these steps but it is giving me error..similar to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662981/soundtouch-building-with-android-ndk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully compiled by changing my `android.mk` file :

here is my `android.mk` file

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += -fno-exceptions

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
     SoundTouch/AAFilter.cpp \
     SoundTouch/BPMDetect.cpp \
     SoundTouch/cpu_detect_x86.cpp\
      SoundTouch/FIFOSampleBuffer.cpp \
      SoundTouch/FIRFilter.cpp \
      SoundTouch/mmx_optimized.cpp \
      SoundTouch/PeakFinder.cpp \
      SoundTouch/RateTransposer.cpp \
      SoundTouch/SoundTouch.cpp \
      SoundTouch/sse_optimized.cpp \
      SoundTouch/TDStretch.cpp 

LOCAL_MODULE := libSoundTouch

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := include/BPMDetect.h include/FIFOSampleBuffer.h include/FIFOSamplePipe.h include/SoundTouch.h include/STTypes.h

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Can any one help with using this library?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [THIS](https://github.com/VladimirKulyk/SoundTouch-Android) link this guy already compiled ready to use SoundTouch Android wrapper.

> - Currently capable of time-stretching and pitch shifting.
> - Currently only supports Androids with an FPU (armeabi-v7a).

Example usage:

```
//There are currently 16 track id's you can use (0-15), each one has a separate SoundTouch processor.

    //Set your audio processing requirements: track id, channels, samplingRate, bytesPerSample, 
    //                              tempoChange (1.0 is normal speed), pitchChange (in semi-tones)

    SoundTouch soundTouch = new SoundTouch(0, 2, 44100, 2, 1.0f, 2.0f);

    //byte[] sizes are recommended to be 8192 bytes.

    //put a byte[] of PCM audio in the sound processor:
    soundTouch.putBytes(input);

    //write output to a byte[]:
    int bytesReceived = soundTouch.getBytes(output);

    //after you write the last byte[], call finish().
    soundTouch.finish();

    //now get the remaining bytes from the sound processor.
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    do
    {
        bytesReceived = soundTouch.getBytes(output);
        //do stuff with output.
    } while (bytesReceived != 0)

    //if you stop playing, call clear on the track to clear the pipeline for later use.
    soundTouch.clearBuffer()
```

> **Visit above github link for more details.**

Comment: The guy has moved code base to new repo on github I've updated the link. [NEW LINK IS THIS](https://github.com/VladimirKulyk/SoundTouch-Android)