# Soundtouch building with Android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, soundtouch

I'm trying to import Soundtouch library in my Android project, but I'm not a native code power user, so that's probably why I'm having some issues understanding the way the building is supposed to be done. 
I tried to follow his guidelines: 
[Android : Help in compiling SoundTouch lib in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289145/android-help-in-compiling-soundtouch-lib-in-android) 
That means, I created 2 folders(**include/** and **SoundTouch/**) and I respectively inserted the headers and the .cpp files. 
Afterwards, I used his *Android.mk* and when I tried to *ndk-build*, I got this:

`Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring invalid values in LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES definition in /home/user/workspace/Player/jni/Android.mk: -fno-exceptions

Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring invalid values in LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES definition in /home/user/workspace/Player/jni/Android.mk: -fno-exceptions

make: *** No rule to make target /home/user/Downloads/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/SoundTouch/AAFilter.cpp', needed by /home/user/workspace/Player/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/SoundTouch/SoundTouch/AAFilter.o'.  Stop.`

As far as I read, I can remove the *-fno-exceptions* flag since in newer versions of the NDK the exception handling is disabled by default, but I don't get what's wrong about the *make* part. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file is missing. Check that it actually exists at that path.