# Porting SoundTouch for Android

Tags: android, audio, java-native-interface, soundtouch

I have been trying to write an application for Android that will allow me to slow down and speed up music in real time. I came across the SoundTouch library, which even states that it can be used in Android via the jni. However, the source only converts the getversionString() method to andorid. I have found several other implementations of this library, such as https://github.com/nonameentername/soundtouch-android, but it is missing a the crucial file, and thus will not compile. I have also tried porting a Desktop application, called Mypodconv (http://www.aplu.ch/home/apluhomex.jsp?site=44), to Android, but this uses the javax.sound package contained within rt.jar which is too big for android and thus causes a heap overflow and crashes eclipse. Does anybody know how I can make this library work in android? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Help in compiling SoundTouch lib in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289145/android-help-in-compiling-soundtouch-lib-in-android)

Comment: If you're still looking I'm working on a wrapper - https://github.com/svenoaks/SoundTouch-Android - currently working good on 16 bit samples.