# How to change pitch of audio without changing its duration using OpenSL ES or other C/C++ code in Android?

Tags: android, c++, c, audio

I have problem with changing pitch of audio keeping its duration. I want to change pitch of audio and simultaneously don't change its speed.

I compiled [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260177/6296729) but setPitch() method is empty..

**Can anyone give me a solution or some hints how to do it using OpenSL ES or other C/C++ code?**

I know that java isn't good to do this so I want to do it using C/C++ code.

Sorry for my English! Thanks!

Comment: This is a very big question, and possibly more suited to dsp stack exchange. You're looking for a pitchshifter

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I asked there. But if there is anyone who know answer, I would appreciate if I get the soution.

Answer (score 2):

The **[SoundTouch Audio Processing Library](https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/)** has been developped for that purpose.

It is a great library, but online examples (or documentation) are hard to find. You may have to read the [source files](https://github.com/alexmarsev/soundtouch/blob/master/include/SoundTouch.h) to find out how to use it.

This is [how it works internally](https://www.surina.net/article/time-and-pitch-scaling.html).

You can see the results of a song processed with their library, performing various pitch alterations without altering the tempo [here](https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/soundstretch.html#examples).

---

### EDIT

As of today, I prefer using [RubberBand](https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/): it usually gives more qualitative results.

Comment: Yes, I saw this library but I tried meny times to add this to my existing project and it didn't work.. Maybe you know how to add this to exusting Android Studio project?

Comment: Found this related question on SO, tell me if it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289145/android-help-in-compiling-soundtouch-lib-in-android